# Django ForeignKey filter issue

Tags: python, django

Is there anyway to add filter on django foreignkey field.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You can just use the `key__` syntax like this:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(category__name='Tops')
```

Just make sure what is after the `__` appears in the `Category` model and you will be good to go.  You can read more [about how django handles cross-relationship `filter`ing here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

---

You can also just query by the related ID itself:

```
category = Category.objects.get(id=25)
products = Producct.objects.filter(category_id=25)
```

Comment: I'm using `group = models.ForeignKey(Category.objects.filter(group__category__name="foo"))` but got error `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Comment: This means you aren’t using django with the standard manage.py.  If that is the case:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready