# "Apps aren't loaded yet" when trying to run pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

Using the (partial) polls app from the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) as an example, I'm trying to get [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run.

Using the command `django-admin startproject mysite2`, I've created a project directory with the following structure:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── polls
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── pytest.ini
```

My `pytest.ini` looks like

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = mysite2.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Following the tutorial, in `polls/models.py` I've created `Question` and `Choice` models:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Now, if I make `tests.py` as described in the tutorial, which is based on Python's built-in `unittest` module,

```
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Question

class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
```

and I run `python manage.py test` from the command line, the test fails expected:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_was_published_recently_with_future_question (polls.tests.QuestionModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch/mysite2/polls/tests.py", line 23, in test_was_published_recently_with_future_question
    self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
AssertionError: True is not False

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

However, if I change the testing code to the (attempted) `pytest` equivalent (that is, without having to subclass `TestCase` and with ordinary assertions):

```
def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question():
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
    assert future_question.was_published_recently() is False
```

and run the `pytest` command, I get the following error:

```
================================= test session starts ==================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch/mysite2, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: timeout-1.2.1
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                            

======================================== ERRORS ========================================
___________________________ ERROR collecting polls/tests.py ____________________________
polls/tests.py:10: in <module>
    from .models import Question
polls/models.py:6: in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:100: in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:244: in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py:127: in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
E   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.64 seconds ================================
```

So far I haven't been able to find a way to fix this. Any ideas on how to get the test to run?

Comment: Ensure `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set. Took me ages to figure out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Out of the box, `pytest` doesn't know about the Django database, even with `pytest-django` installed. Never fear, though: `pytest-django` makes it easy for your tests to access the Django database using its [django_db pytest mark](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#enabling-database-access-in-tests).

Give this a try:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question():
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
    assert future_question.was_published_recently() is False
```

Comment: I had similar issue. To whoever stumbles upon the same error: `pip uninstall django-pytest` and `pip install pytest-django` instead.

Comment: This worked for me . confusing how there is a django-pytest too!

Comment: @AlexPavlenko, what an MVP

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when invoking tests either with `pytest` or `python setup.py test`.

For `pytest` invocation installing `pytest-django` in my virtual env solved the problem.

For `python setup.py install` adding `pytest-django` to the `tests_require` argument of `setup()` solved it.

Here's the snippet of `setup.py`:

```
TEST_REQUIREMENTS = [
    'pytest',
    'pytest-django',
    'pylint',
    'pylint_django',
    'git-pylint-commit-hook',
]

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Foo package',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    packages=['foo'],
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIREMENTS,
    setup_requires=SETUP_REQUIREMENTS,
    tests_require=TEST_REQUIREMENTS,
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho. pytest-django is the glue that solves the problem and makes Django and pytest friends.

Comment: Yes that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

According to [Django: AppRegistryNotReady()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready), when not using `manage.py` one must call `django.setup()` explicitly. I verified this by running the `pytest` test from a `manage.py` shell:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro:mysite2 kurtpeek$ python3 manage.py shell
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pytest

In [2]: pytest.main('polls/tests.py')
================================= test session starts ==================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Scratch/mysite2, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: timeout-1.2.1
collected 1 item                                                                        

polls/tests.py F

======================================= FAILURES =======================================
___________________ test_was_published_recently_with_future_question ___________________

    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question():
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
>       assert future_question.was_published_recently() is False
E    assert True is False
E     +  where True = <bound method Question.was_published_recently of <Question: >>()
E     +    where <bound method Question.was_published_recently of <Question: >> = <Question: >.was_published_recently

polls/tests.py:18: AssertionError
=================================== warnings summary ===================================
None
  passing a string to pytest.main() is deprecated, pass a list of arguments instead.

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
========================= 1 failed, 1 warnings in 0.14 seconds =========================
Out[2]: 1
```

This is not really an acceptable solution, however, as the tests need to be runnable from the command line. Are there perhaps other `pytest` decorators to ensure the required setup?

Answer (score 1):

For me, setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as an export on the command line or in the pytest.ini solved the problem.
It seems to ignore the export of that env var in conftest.py
If I figure it out I will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

Does it say somewhere in the docs that the test should work without subclassing `django.test.TestCase`? I don't think that `django-pytest` does anything special in regards to loading django apps. So, if your class continues to inherit from `TestCase`, you should be able to use everything else from `pytest`, such as it's assertions, fixtures, etc.

Comment: Interesting idea, but according to the [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), "Less boilerplate: no need to import unittest, create a subclass with methods. Just write tests as regular functions." should be one of the advantages of `pytest-django`, so the subclassing should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just by installing `pytest-django` in addition to existing `pytest`, the error was gone for me as well :D

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I forgot to add `pytest.ini` to link `pytest` to my project settings - see the [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
# -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test.settings
# -- recommended but optional:
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to run pytest without starting up django, you might encounter this kind of issue.

To resolve the `Apps aren't loaded yet` error, I made the following changes:

1. Created a `test_settings.py` file: I created a new file named test_settings.py in the config directory of my Django app with the same content from my `settings.py`.
2. Imported `django` module and added `django.setup()` in the `test_settings.py` after other module imports and startup configurations.

This allowed me to initialize the Django app registry and other necessary components before running the tests.

Here's how the `test_settings.py` file looks:

```
# test_settings.py

import django
... (other module imports and configurations)
django.setup()
```

By adding these two lines, the `Apps aren't loaded yet` error was resolved, and I was able to run my tests using pytest without any issues.

Here's my project structure:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── app
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   ├── celery_beat_schedules.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── test_settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── decorators.py
│   │   ├── enums.py
│   │   ├── management
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── commands
│   │   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │   │       └── wait_for_db.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── services.py
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   │   ├── factories.py
│   │   │   ├── models
│   │   │   │   └── test_kr.py
│   │   │   └── views
│   │   │       └── test_search_member.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── pytest.ini
```

Additional Note:
It's important to ensure you have the `pytest` and `pytest-django` packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

inspired by the answer above by @Peter Varshavsky
I had pytest installed, but invoking `pytest` was giving that error.
so installed `pytest-django`, then i created a `pytest.ini` file in the root directory with

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = projectname.settings
```

it also works if you just export the variable before running the command `pytest`.
now if i invoke `pytest`, it works succeussfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the conftest.py file made the following changes before importing any other models / files.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<MODULE_NAME>.settings")

import django
django.setup()
```

The above snippets helped me to resolve the issue for me.