# How to create python script to add row inside database in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I tried to run this script but definitely something missing here...
**mysite** this is the app, **School** is the class

```
from mysite.models import School
school1 = School(name='Oxford school', address='Shole St.33', email='ox-scholl@gmail.com', phone_number='3445348910')
school1.save()
```

And get this error: **raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.**

Comment: How to load an app inside python script?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j7w6yx                    # same error

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j7whx5

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready

Answer (score 0):

As Ganesh Negi mentioned:  [Django: AppRegistryNotReady()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready?noredirect=1&lq=1), but you can also use [**fixtures**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/initial-data/)