# Why do I get a django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Why do I get this error?

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady

Comment: please post complete error trace

Comment: try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793351/django-appregistrynotready

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Django documentation on exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#appregistrynotready)

> This exception is raised when attempting to use models before the app loading process, which initializes the ORM, is complete.